# nc command's -k option

Tags: netcat

man page of the nc command has following information

> -k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.  It
>                is an error to use this option without the -l option.

But `nc --help` output has not any information regarding to -k option.

And when I try to capture packages like

> nc -kl -i 86400 -p 44444 > nc_44444.dmp

I got following error

> netcat: invalid option -- 'k'

So what is the problem ? Is there any option called as "-k"

My problem is I have to capture some data from network and sometimes client application could disconnect from server port and it could reconnect again. So I don't want to get problem about disconnect/reconnect events

Comment: # uname -a
Linux  2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: # cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: Name        : nc
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.84
Release     : 22.el6
Size        : 109 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : RHELServer
Summary     : Reads and writes data across network connections using TCP or UDP
URL         : http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/

Comment: Please provide the full output from running `nc -h`.  I suspect you're running busybox `nc`, which doesn't support `-k`.  Regular `nc` has supported the `-k` option since at least 2001 [source](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/netcat.c?rev=1.27&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).

Comment: Where "regular" means the OpenBSD version, that everybody these days seems to use, rather than [nc110](http://sourceforge.net/p/nc110/code/HEAD/tree/nc110/netcat.c) from 1996.

Comment: Debian (wheezy) defaults to providing `nc` from the package `netcat-traditional`, which has very few options and certainly nothing so newfangled as `-k`. Fortunately there is also `netcat-openbsd`, but it has to be installed manually.

Comment: S O L V  E  D  
The consultant installed netcat so I uninstalled netcat and then nc was not working. So I also removed and reinstalled nc again.  
Now -k option is working now  
Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're not using the `netcat` command you think. ie, check the result of `which nc`. As for me (CentOS 6.6), it's `/usr/bin/nc` and `-k` option works. However, correct syntax would be:

```
nc -l -k -i 86400 localhost 44444 > nc_44444.dmp
```

If you can't make it work, consider using `ncat` which is part of `nmap` package. (there are many *netcat* implementations...)

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error with `GNU netcat 0.7.1`. The flag is supported by the BSD version of `nc`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, *your version* of nc doesn't have the `-k` option. You could upgrade, or, as a workaround, run without `-k` in a loop.